# Dynamic Database change in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using `DB::disconnect` and `DB::reconnection` for connect database for multi tenant system in Laravel 5.2.

**The code is as:**

```
DB::disconnect();
Config::set('database.connections.mysql', $config);
DB::reconnect();
```

Where $config is an array of configurations to be set, this is working fine when I have to change the only database name, but when I want to change the prefix for the database it is not working, every time it takes old database.

I have tried to `config:cache` from the Middleware where I change the connection but it removes all input variables.

So, What Can I do to change prefix of DB connection? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to purge the cache of the database object:

```
// Will disconnect automatically
DB::purge('mysql');

// Register new config
Config::set('database.connections.mysql', $config);

// Will reconnect automatically
DB::table('table')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is anything in laravel that prevent cache for database?

Comment: I don't think there is. "Databse cache" means "sql connection" — that means if you have no DB cache, laravel will connect and disconnect everytime a query is made (which is low performance and stressing proof)